# Select a Bluetooth device from ListView and open a new Intent (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, bluetooth

I am doing an Android app which turns on Bluetooth and displays the paired devices.
The paired devices are shown in a ListView but I also want to click on a specific Bluetooth device (let's call it BTDEVICE03), and open a new Intent if the device matches the name BTDEVICE03.

Is it doable? Here is the code:

```
package com.example.homie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private Button On,Off,Visible,list;
   private BluetoothAdapter BA;
   private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
   private ListView lv;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      On = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      Off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      Visible = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
      list = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

      lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

      BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
   }



   public void on(View view){
      if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
         Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
         startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turned on" 
         ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Already on",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
   }
   public void list(View view){
      pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
         list.add(bt.getName());

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Showing Paired Devices",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);




   }
   public void off(View view){
      BA.disable();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turned off" ,
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   public void visible(View view){
      Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.
      ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
      startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);

   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add a onClickListener to act when an item is clicked. Then, you will have to compare and start the intent.

```
public void list(View view){
    pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
       list.add(bt.getName());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Showing Paired Devices",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (list.get(position).equals("BTDEVICE03") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClassHere.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```